# Pass URL parameters to a flutter single page app

Tags: flutter, dart, url, single-page-application

I have written a flutter SPA. The URL for the app looks like this:

https://acmecorp.web.app/#/

and any pages visited do not show an updated URL (because I don't want people to share individual pages within the app).

However, I would like to capture an optional parameter (user id) when users are directed to the site, something like this:

https://acmecorp.web.app/#/uid or https://acmecorp.web.app/#/?uid=test

. Once the uid is captured by the start page and set as a local variable, I don't need this uid to survive in the URL bar.

I have tried using `html.window.location.href` and variations of this to try to capture the uid, which was unsuccessful. I understand that the pound sign signals a URL fragment so things after it are stripped, but even playing with the position of the parameters has not helped e.g. `https://acmecorp.web.app?uid=test/#/` or `https://acmecorp.web.app/?uid=test#/`.

I also tried messing around with gorouter in `main.dart`

```
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
              builder: (context, state) => StartPageWidget(
                uid: state.queryParams['did'],
              ),
      ),
    ],
  );
```

with limited success, as I then have the problem that it seems to ruin the routing when I try to navigate to the other pages.

This seems like something super simple and I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm a data scientist so pretty new to this!... I do recall being able to do this in angular quite easily.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to grab the query parameters in your `main` before the `runApp`. Then, even though the URL gets re-written in routing, you still have the original URL and query available.

Comment: The go-router approach is correct. Please provide more details on this "limited success" so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Uri.base](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/base.html) to capture query parameters like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(uid: Uri.base.queryParameters['uid']),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key, required this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  final String? uid;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text(uid ?? 'No uid')),
    );
  }
}
```